# What is the probability of getting from point $A$ to point $B$ given each path has $1-p$ of being open?

Tags: probability

[image]

What is the probability of getting from point A to point B, given that the probability of each line segment being close is p and being open is (1-p) and each line segment is independent of the others?

For this I used the inclusion-exclusion rule for a set of 4.
P1=Top path open
P2=Bottom path open
P3=Top left, middle, bottom right being open
P4=Bottom left, middle, top right being open
Seems reasonable but not 100% sure if it's the right approach?

Comment: When you say "the probability of each path being open is $1-p$", do you mean each line segment in the drawing? Or do you mean each path that you've enumerated?

Comment: Also, are there any restrictions, such as a line segment can only be used once?

Comment: line segment and no there's no limitation on how many times each line segment can be used

Comment: Are you asking about a static configuration of open/closed paths or are they opening and closing as you traverse the graph?

Comment: it's static and determined beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the inclusion-exclusion calculation as a sanity check:
\begin{align}
&[2(1-p)^2+2(1-p)^3]-[5(1-p)^4+(1-p)^5]
+4(1-p)^5
-(1-p)^5 \\
&=1-2 p^2 - 2 p^3 + 5 p^4  - 2 p^5
\end{align}
But it doesn't match @MatthewDaly's $1-p- 2 p^3 + 3 p^4 - p^5$.  Both formulas correctly yield $1$ when $p=0$ and $0$ when $p=1$.

The discrepancy is because there are 16 successful arrangements, not 13.  If you correctly include [bcde/a], [acd/be], and [abe/cd], Matthew's approach yields: 
$$(1−p)^5+5p(1−p)^4+8p^2(1−p)^3+2p^3(1−p)^2 = 1-2 p^2 - 2 p^3 + 5 p^4  - 2 p^5,$$
which agrees with my inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

I will call "success" a path from A to B.

You will be successful every time there are four or five open paths.  There are exactly eight ways to have success with three open paths (the two top edges and any other edge, the two bottom edges and any other edge, and the two length-3 paths that include the middle edge).  Finally, there are exactly two successes with exactly two open paths.

Since the probability of a path being closed is $p$ and the five edges are all independent, the final probability of success is 
$$(1-p)^5+5p(1-p)^4+8p^2(1-p)^3+2p^3(1-p)^2$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $4p(1-p)^4$ rather than $3p(1-p)^4$?

Comment: Yup.  Thanks for catching it!

Comment: So how come my initial intuition about applying inclusion-exclusion principle doesn't work in this case?

Comment: What about [bcde/a]?

Comment: @RobPratt Sorry, I did a lousy job of countinh.  I missed that and two of the length-3 paths as well.  I reformed my argument in such a way that it is clearer that I have all of the paths this time.  Sorry again!